# Another ordinals question $\sum_{i\in\omega +3} i\cdot\omega + \omega\cdot i$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

So I have to calculate sum $$ \sum_{i\in\omega +3} i\cdot\omega + \omega\cdot i$$
If I got it right, $1\cdot\omega+2\cdot\omega+\dots+(\omega-1)\cdot\omega = \omega\cdot(\omega-1)$
Then I have to calculate this:
$\omega\cdot1+\omega\cdot2+\dots+\omega\cdot(\omega-1)+\omega\cdot(\omega-1)$
And I don't have idea how to approach it. If I go by natural numbers formula i get division by 2 and I cant find that case in ordinal arithmetics.

Comment: Well, you have to be more careful: $\sum (x_i+y_i)$ is not the same as $\sum x_i + \sum y_i$ in ordinal arithmetic

Comment: And again, $(\omega-1)$ is not defined. Actually, it's better to never think about subtraction in ordinal arithmetic. Neither is division, by the way.

Comment: Yes I know but eventually, by law of assotiation i can permutate equation to look like this.

Comment: No, you can't, since $\omega-1$ is not a thing that is defined. If you're talking about reordering the terms, that needs commutativity, not associativity. Ordinal arithmetic lacks commutativity. Instead of working with reordering sums or with subtraction, try working with suprema. Think of it as a limit.

Comment: But how to aproach this if I cant use that, how to calculate $ \sum_{i\in\omega+1} i\cdot\omega $

Comment: Im not reordering it, just writing $ \omega*2 $as $\omega+\omega$ and then reordering the brackets.

Comment: Ok I thought about the things you said but I came to deadend because now i have to calculate $\sum_{i\in\omega} \omega\cdot(i+1)$ could you reply please what could I do with this?

Comment: As is the case with regular series, you want to think about the "partial sums" if you ever try to do something like splitting the sum up into two different sums or anything like that. Observe that you can deduce simple inequalities, such as$$\omega\cdot n\le\sum_{i\in n+1}(i\cdot\omega+\omega\cdot i)\le\omega^2$$from which the result becomes obvious.

Answer (score 2):

By associativity, we have:

\begin{align}
\sum_{i\in\omega+3}i\cdot\omega+\omega\cdot i\quad=\quad
&\left(\sum_{i\in\omega}i\cdot\omega+\omega\cdot i\right)\\
&+\quad (\omega\cdot\omega+\omega\cdot\omega)\\
&+\quad((\omega+1)\cdot\omega+\omega\cdot(\omega+1))\\
&+\quad((\omega+2)\cdot\omega+\omega\cdot(\omega+2))
\end{align}

Some of these terms are easy, so I hope you agree with the following:
\begin{align}
&\omega\cdot\omega+\omega\cdot\omega=\omega^2+\omega^2=\omega^2\cdot 2\\
&\omega\cdot(\omega+1)=\omega^2+\omega\\
&\omega\cdot(\omega+2)=\omega\cdot(\omega+1)+\omega=\omega^2+\omega+\omega=\omega^2+\omega\cdot 2
\end{align}
For the rest we need to reason with limits. For example $(\omega+1)\cdot \omega$ is the supremum of the set $\{(\omega+1)\cdot\gamma\mid\gamma\in\omega\}$. You can prove that $(\omega+1)\cdot\gamma=\omega\cdot\gamma+1$ for any $\gamma\geq1$:

> If $\gamma=1$ we have $(\omega+1)\cdot 1=\omega+1$
>
> If $\gamma=\beta+1$, we have $(\omega+1)\cdot(\beta+1)=(\omega+1)\cdot\beta+(\omega+1)$. Using the induction hypothesis this equals $(\omega\cdot\beta+1)+(\omega+1)=\omega\cdot\beta+(1+\omega)+1=\omega\cdot\beta+\omega+1=\omega\cdot(\beta+1)+1$.

Hence we see that $(\omega+1)\cdot\omega$ is the supremum of $\{\omega\cdot\gamma +1\mid\gamma\in\omega\}$. You can show that $\omega\cdot\gamma+1$ is unbounded in $\omega^2$ (hint: if $\alpha\in\omega^2$, then $\alpha<\omega\cdot\beta$ for some $\beta\in\omega$), and you can show that $\omega\cdot\gamma+1<\omega^2$ for any $\gamma\in\omega$. Therefore the supremum of this set is $\omega^2$. So we see that $(\omega+1)\cdot\omega=\omega^2$.

In a similar way you can compute $(\omega+2)\cdot\omega$.

---

Now all that is left is $\sum_{i\in\omega}i\cdot\omega+\omega\cdot i$. However, this becomes quite easy: $i\cdot\omega=\omega$ for any $i\in\omega$ (I showed how to prove this in my answer to your previous question), and $\omega\cdot i$ is just $\omega\cdot i$. Finally note that $\omega+\omega\cdot i=\omega\cdot(i+1)$ (prove this by induction).

So we have $\sum_{i\in\omega}i\cdot\omega+\omega\cdot i=(\omega\cdot 2)+(\omega\cdot 3)+(\omega\cdot 4)+\dots$. It is not too difficult to show that this is equal to $\omega^2$.

---

So, if I made no mistakes, in conclusion we should have:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i\in\omega+3}i\cdot\omega+\omega\cdot i\quad=\quad
&\quad\omega^2\\
&+\quad \omega^2\cdot 2\\
&+\quad\omega^2+\omega^2+\omega\\
&+\quad\omega^2+\omega^2+\omega\cdot 2\\
=\quad&\omega^2\cdot 7+\omega\cdot 2
\end{align}

---

Note that we never reason with subtraction, division or reordering addition / multiplication, since these things are *invalid* in ordinal arithmetic. Instead, we reason with unboundedness, to show suprema are larger than or equal to a given ordinal, and with boundedness to show suprema are smaller than or equal to a given ordinal. This is the way you should think about ordinal addition.

As with all mathematics, the only way to really get comfortable with this is by practice, so I encourage you to try computing some different sums yourself.

Comment: Oh thank you so much, you saved my exam. I can understand it now, everything is clear. Can you please just give me hint how to prove that last sum if you have more spare time ?

Comment: No, I'll leave that as an exercise in computing suprema.

Comment: Oh I see that now, w+w+w+...=w*n+w*n+... =w^2. Thanksss

Comment: Multiplying by integers doesn't matter because it is the same as adding them.

Comment: Intuitively, yes, but it's better to reason that a partial sum of $\omega+\omega+\dots$ is larger than any $\alpha<\omega^2$ and that the partial sums are unbounded in $\omega^2$. Note that you also need that addition is order-preserving, which is another thing that should be proved...

Comment: Another good exercise, try to show that $$\sum_{i\in\omega+3}i\cdot\omega+\sum_{i\in\omega+3}\omega\cdot i$$ has a different value than the sum from your exercise.

Comment: I got $ (\omega^2)\cdot 8 + \omega\cdot 3 $

Comment: And from the one you didi I got $ \omega^2 \cdot 7 + \omega \cdot 3 $ I think you missed $\omega$

Comment: It should be $\omega\cdot2$, since $\omega+\omega^2=\omega^2$ (why?). Other than that, good job!

Comment: Oh I didn't know that thanks, its $ \omega^2 \cdot 8+ \omega \cdot 2 $ then for the exercise one.

Comment: Because $ \omega + \omega^2 = \omega\cdot(1+\omega) =\omega\cdot\omega =\omega^2 $ I think.